# Copy Dragged folder(items) into temp folder in swift macOS

Tags: ios, macos

Does any one has idea how to copy Dragged folder(items) into temp folder while drag and drop

Comment: I has an idea to handle dragged files but need to know how to handle folders items

Comment: Please limit your questions to anything related to programming.

Answer (score -1):

Without any details, I anyway suggest to read this [excellent tutorial](https://www.natethompson.io/2019/03/23/nstableview-drag-and-drop.html).

For UI Swift is simpler:

```
struct ContentView: View, DropDelegate {
    @State private var dragging = false
    let TYPE = (kUTTypeFileURL as String)
    var body: some View {
        Text("drag here!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .border(dragAreaBorder, width: 5)
            .onDrop(of: [TYPE], delegate: self)
    }

    var dragAreaBorder: Color {
        return dragging ? .accentColor : .yellow
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        dragging = true
        let proposal = DropProposal.init(operation: .copy)
        return proposal
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        let itemProviders = info.itemProviders(for: [TYPE])

        for itemProvider in itemProviders{
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: TYPE, options: nil) { item, error in
            guard let data = item as? Data, let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil) else { return }

            // remember to dispatch on main in case of a @State change

            //print(url)
            process(url: url)
        }

        self.dragging = false

        return true
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }

    func process(url: URL){

        let isDirectory = url.hasDirectoryPath
        if !isDirectory{
        let path = url.path
            doTaskFor(sourcePath: path, callback: callback)
            return
        }

        let fm = FileManager.default
        // is a dir:
        guard let files = try? fm.contentsOfDirectory(at : url,
                              includingPropertiesForKeys : nil,
                                                 options : [] ) else {
                                                     return
                                                 }
        for url in files{
        //..... what ever...
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24568558)

Comment: I do not agree. answer does: a) give a useful link to a tutorial b) I give a working sample... so?